# Get first element from HashMap

Tags: hashmap, iterator, rust

I have a `HashMap` and need to get the first element:

```
type VarIdx = std::collections::HashMap<u16, u8>;

fn get_first_elem(idx: VarIdx) -> u16 {
    let it = idx.iter();
    let ret = match it.next() {
        Some(x) => x,
        None => -1,
    };
    ret
}

fn main() {}
```

but the code doesn't compile:

```
error[E0308]: match arms have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |       let ret = match it.next() {
  |  _______________^
6 | |         Some(x) => x,
7 | |         None => -1,
8 | |     };
  | |_____^ expected tuple, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `(&u16, &u8)`
             found type `{integer}`
note: match arm with an incompatible type
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
7 |         None => -1,
  |                 ^^
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd **strongly** encourage you to read the documentation of any method you are calling, especially when you get an error. For example, [`HashMap::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter) has a *tiny* amount of documentation that explains all of your problems: "An iterator visiting all key-value pairs in arbitrary order. The iterator element type is `(&'a K, &'a V)`."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "first" item in a `HashMap`. There are [no guarantees about the order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter) in which the values are stored nor the order in which you will iterate over them.

If order is important then perhaps you can switch to a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html), which preserves order based on the keys.

If you just need to get the first value *that you come across*, in other words *any* value, you can do something similar to your original code: create an iterator, just taking the first value:

```
fn get_first_elem(idx: VarIdx) -> i16 {
    match idx.values().next() {
        Some(&x) => x as i16,
        None => -1,
    }
}
```

The method `values()` creates an iterator over just the values. The reason for your error is that `iter()` will create an iterator over pairs of keys and values which is why you got the error *"expected tuple"*.

To make it compile, I had to change a couple of other things: `-1` is not a valid `u16` value so that had to become `i16`, and your values are `u8` so had to be cast to `i16`.

As another general commentary, returning `-1` to indicate failure is not very "Rusty". This is what `Option` is for and, given that `next()` already returns an `Option`, this is very easy to accomplish:

```
fn get_first_elem(idx: VarIdx) -> Option<u8> {
    idx.values().copied().next()
}
```

The `.copied()` is needed in order to convert the `&u8` values of the iterator into `u8`.

Answer (score 7):

`HashMap::iter` returns an iterator over `(&Key, &Value)` pairs. What you want is `HashMap::values`, which produces an iterator that only produces the values of the `HashMap`.

Note that the order of the values is random. It has nothing to do with the order you put the values in or with the actual value of the values.