# Why does HashMap::iter.nth(0) give different output for each execution run?

Tags: hashmap, iterator, rust

Given the below program:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(0, 1);
    hm.insert(1, 1);
    let mut iter = hm.iter();
    println!("{:?}", iter.nth(0).expect("Fatal.").0)
}
```

I get a different output for each execution run of the code:

```
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
     Running `target/debug/t1`
1
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ vim src/main.rs 
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ cargo run
   Compiling t1 v0.1.0 (file:///home/procyclinsur/Documents/Rust/t1)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.12 secs
     Running `target/debug/t1`
1
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
     Running `target/debug/t1`
1
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
     Running `target/debug/t1`
0
procyclinsur@procyclinsur:~/Documents/Rust/t1$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.0 secs
     Running `target/debug/t1`
1
```

I'd expect that I should see the same output for each run of the program. Does anyone know the reason why this code behaves in such a way? How do I get this to output only 0 as expected?

Comment: See also [Get first element from HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45194220/155423).

Comment: @Stargateur Fixed!

Comment: @Shepmaster Your right, that post does answer my question, however it does not do so in an obvious way.  It's title is not indicative of the problem I was referring to, nor is the example code or explanation.  This post has a better description of the actual problem.  There should be a better way of solving this besides just marking this as a duplicate?

Comment: that's actually the perfect use case for duplicates. They serve as signposts that redirect people that search for different terminology, getting them all to one canonical set of answers. There's absolutely *nothing* bad about having your question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: The down vote was for the output as image, which you've fixed so I've removed; thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a `HashMap` is unordered. Its [`iter` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter)

> visits all key-value pairs in **arbitrary** order

The [documentation on collections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/#iterators) describes this behavior:

> For **unordered collections like HashMap**, the items will be yielded in
>   whatever order the internal representation made most convenient.

In order to always retrieve a specific value you need to [search by the key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) (or use one of the [`Iterator` methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.Iter.html#impl-Iterator) that don't depend on the order, e.g. [`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find)); for example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(0, "a");
    hm.insert(1, "b");
    println!("{:?}", hm.get(&0)) // always Some("a")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the order is not predictable. However, using a different hasher can at least give you *reproducible* results. For example the [FNV hash function](https://crates.io/crates/fnv), which you can use like this:

```
extern crate fnv;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;
use fnv::FnvHasher;

type HashMapFnv<K, V> = HashMap<K, V, BuildHasherDefault<FnvHasher>>;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMapFnv::default();
    hm.insert(0, 1);
    hm.insert(1, 1);
    let mut iter = hm.iter();
    println!("{:?}", iter.nth(0).expect("Fatal.").0)
}
```

This should give you the same results each time. However, there are no guarantees about what that order is, so you might get different results on a different operating system, if you update FNV or if you use a different version of Rust itself.

Note that you shouldn't use this hash function in any application that processes external data, as it is be vulnerable to hash collision attacks. The default hash function in Rust is safe.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning `BTreeMap` and corresponding [iter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.iter) function

> Gets an iterator over the entries of the map, sorted by key.

This may be a simple drop-in replacement.

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hm = BTreeMap::new();
    hm.insert(0, 1);
    hm.insert(1, 1);
    let mut iter = hm.iter();
    println!("{:?}", iter.nth(0).expect("Fatal.").0);
}
```

[playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=099f64c37213eb08dcfe7d4a05860c5b&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: Thanks for the BTreeMap mention, this seems interesting, I will check it out!